# CCMenuItemLabelAndSprite and CCSprite from CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, menuitem

I'm trying to create some Menu Item with Image & Label, using [barry's class](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/19789#post-116070)

```
    CGRect menuItemRect = CGRectFromString([[myAtlas objectForKey:@"menuItem.png"] objectForKey:@"textureRect"]);
    CCSprite *normalMenuItemSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithBatchNode:batchNode rect:menuItemRect];
    CCSprite *selectedMenuItemSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithBatchNode:batchNode rect:menuItemRect];

    CCMenuItemLabelAndSprite *aMenuItem = [CCMenuItemLabelAndSprite itemWithLabel:itemLabel normalSprite:normalMenuItemSprite selectedSprite:selectedMenuItemSprite];

    CCMenu *myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:aMenuItem, nil];
    myMenu.anchorPoint = ccpzero;
    myMenu.position = ccp(330,280);
    [myMenu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:100];
    [self addChild:myMenu];
```

**If CCSprite is being rendered by CCSpriteBatchNode, CCSprite#draw SHOULD NOT be called** is the error that shows up in my log

I know that I can't add any others objects beside CCSprites to CCSpriteBatchNode but how can I deal with this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `spriteWithSpriteFrameName`

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"myAtlas.plist"];

CCSprite *normalMenuItemSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"menuItem.png"];
```